# How to move to the next YouTube video and collect data about recommended videos?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, youtube, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to make a Python script that plays YouTube videos, get title and channel name of current video and first fifteen recommended ones. After this it should play the next video (first in recommended, autoplay is on). This should be done 5 times. Sound simple enough, but it isn't. The first problem is that sometimes it doesn't move to the next video and keep playing the current one. And even if it skips to the next video all five times, like it should, it doesn't get titles and channel name of the new video and it's recommended. It works all right when I'm not using the for loop.

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
presence = EC.presence_of_element_located
visible = EC.visibility_of_element_located
clickable = EC.element_to_be_clickabledef

get_recommended(self):
    try:
        for i in range(5):
            wait.until(presence((By.ID, "related")))
            recommended = wait.until(visible((By.ID, "related")))

            titles = []
            channels = []
            video_counter = 0

            while video_counter < 15:
                titles = recommended.find_elements_by_id("video-title")
                channels = recommended.find_elements_by_id("channel-name")
                video_counter = len(titles)

            curr_title = wait.until(presence((By.TAG_NAME, "h1")))
            element = wait.until(presence((By.ID, "meta-contents")))
            curr_channel = element.find_element_by_id("channel-name")
            print("\nNow playing " + curr_title.text + " By " + curr_channel.text)
            print("Next: " + titles[0].text + " By " + channels[0].text + "\n")

            for video in range(15):
               print(str(video + 1) + ". title:   " + titles[video].text + "  By " + channels[video].text)

            wait.until(clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "style-scope ytd-compact-autoplay-renderer")))
            next_video = titles[0]
            actions = ActionChains(driver)
            actions.move_to_element(next_video).click().perform()                

    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: any error returned by the loop?

Comment: @Jonas No, runs without problems so I guess it's a logical error.